# Why does cite influence the spacing after colons in the IEEEtran \markboth header?

Tags: spacing, ieeetran, cite-package

**Update:** This has been solved in `cite` v5.5.

I noticed that loading (or not) the `cite` package changes the spacing after colons in `\markboth` headings of `IEEEtran`

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
%\usepackage{cite}
\begin{document}
\markboth{: A}{}
: A
\end{document}
```

The differences are subtle, I have to create two pdfs and Alt-Tab between them to see the difference, but it is there.

Why is that, and what can I do before and/or after `\usepackage{cite}` (such as `\let\org...\...` and `\let\...\org...`) to prevent it? I do not see any other difference in an 8-page document except in the headers.

Comment: Donald Arseneau has uploaded a new version of cite to ctan to address this issue.

Comment: I could test it only today (using MikTeX), and cite v5.5 does solve the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One has

```
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
....\OT1/ptm/m/n/7 :
....\glue 2.45004 plus 1.04996 minus 0.84007
....\OT1/ptm/m/n/7
```

The other has

```
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
....\OT1/ptm/m/n/7 :
....\glue 2.87003 plus 2.09991 minus 0.42003
....\OT1/ptm/m/n/7 A
```

The reason is that the spacefactor of `:` has reverted.

the problem only affects the heading as latex normalises the spacefactors in the heading with `\normalsfcodes` which is set or `\frenchspacing` or `\nonfrenchspacing` depending on the value at in force at begin docuemnt.

however the test latex uses is to test if the space factor of `.` is 1000 but `cite` makes it 1001 for its own reasons so the test always fails, so if `cite` is loaded
`\normalsfcodes` always sets the `\nonfrenchspacing` value.

this affects IEEEtran as it defaults to `\frenchspacing`

Simplest fix is to reset `\normalsfcodes`:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}\AtBeginDocument{\let\normalsfcodes\frenchspacing}
\begin{document}

\markboth{: A}{}
: A
\end{document}
```

Comment: I had no recollection of this but checking the latex bugs database since writing the above, the test latex is using was added by me in response to a bug report from the author of the cite package in 1997: http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=latex/2404

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. I leave the discussion where this should best be fixed (`cite` rather than `IEEEtran` rather than TeX, I would assume) to the experts :)

Comment: @bers I dropped a line to Donald A. last night.  Arguably it should be fixed in cite (or at least that's what I'm arguing:-) IEEEtran is (for once) absolved of blame, the other place it could potentially be fixed is for latex to do a less fixed test than `\sfcode\`\.=1000` but it's hard for latex to guess what any possible package might have done, so I think it's easier for cite to just fix it for its own changes.

Answer (score 3):

The cite package has a list of characters

```
\providecommand{\CiteMoveChars}{.,:;}
```

which move the superscript cite after punctuation and this is producing the undesired bahaviour. To prevent this, you can delete the colon from that list:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}

\providecommand{\CiteMoveChars}{.,;}

\begin{document}
\markboth{: A}{}
: A
\end{document}
```

or, load the package with the `nomove` package option (which is the same as removing all initial characters from the move list):

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[nomove]{cite}

\begin{document}
\markboth{: A}{}
: A
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had skipped that part of the `cite` manual because the bottom of page 3 says "Remember, these rules regarding punctuation only apply when the [super] or [superscript] option was given (or overcite.sty used) **and** the [nomove] option was __not__ given."

Now it still does seem to apply...

Comment: nomove avoids the problem but the intention of the code was never to affect the heading in this way, and you might want the feature of moving superscript citations past punctuation without affecting headers.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, you are right. My answer (specially the first one) assumes that removing the colon won't generate any other inconvenience.